# Tying together multiple 14/2

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image: horribleDiagram]

I have my live wire coming into a 2gang switch box. I'm splitting off from their; one wire for two pot lights which one switch will control, a separate wire for the middle one which will be solely controlled by the second switch; then down to a receptacle.

So ultimately I have 4 black and 4 white wires to configure.... i don't think tying all 4 blacks with pigtails (one for each switch and one for the receptacle) is the "right way to go about it?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your plan, it's correct. You need to split the incoming black three ways--to the two switches and the first outlet in the chain.

From the switches you'll run blacks out to your lights. Each switch will have two black wires connected. The white switch loop returns will bundle together with the other whites, including the one from the outlet chain.

[image]

The devices merely indicate wire purpose. Where in your boxes you make the connections is discretionary within the constraints of each box's limit.

Answer (score 1):

If you leave yourself enough wire in the box, you can use a single wire to connect all the devices.  Simply remove a bit of insulation, and loop the exposed wire around the terminal screw of the first device. Then remove a bit more insulation a bit further down the wire, and loop that exposed wire around the screw terminal on the next device. Finally, terminate the end of the wire on the terminal of the last device.

It should look something like this...

[image]

[image]

Even if you didn't leave enough wire in the box, you could make something like this out of a scrap piece of wire. Then simply connect the loose end to the feed with a wire connector.

Comment: oh; interesting. this is an acceptable way to wire? ie up to code etc?

Comment: @Tony Yes, inspectors should be fine with this wiring method.

Comment: @FYI, inspectors hardly ever, if not never look at the wiring behind devices.  Once in a blue moon they may check if "some" boxes are correctly installed to the minimum depth.

Comment: @Kris that's true when inspecting the work of an Electrician.  When checking diy work, some inspectors look a bit closer.

Comment: @Tester101, ahh ha.. good point.  Though I think it is impractical if not impossible for a DIY to apply for a electrical permit since they obviously do not meet the State requirements for electrical work, ergo I have to disagree with you.

Comment: @kris loads of places allow homeowners to do permitted electrical work. I do all my own work, and get permits for all of it.

Comment: @Tester101, you're correct ( as usual ).  Most AHJ do allow homeowners to do small electrical projects, usually after signing an affidavit waiving any liabilities the city may incur from being involved.